# Gravity form with stripe subscription not working "value must match the regex pattern"

Tags: regex, forms, subscription, gravity

I'm having issues with the subscription functionality of [this form](https://bigrockcomms.co.nz/subscribe-24-touch-point-programme-birthday-special/), anyone able to help diagnose the problem?

It keeps saying: "This value must match the regex pattern. (/\A[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\z/ does not match for the value 12monthlypayments_16_1month_492.2)."

Comment: `\A[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\z` does not accept `.`

Comment: Thank you - as for the other question this is a dupe of, I get lost even reading that other page. I'm not an in depth developer, just dabble in it a bit to get things done when necessary. I don't know how to remove the dot since that's the total. I'll try make it a whole number and see if that helps.